# What is a minimal "git rebase" example where the same conflict reappears?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

In the past I've encountered the scenario where a single `git rebase` resulted in me having to resolve the exact same conflict multiple times.
To better understand the preconditions needed to cause this scenario, how can I create a minimal example that recreates this scenario (where I have to resolve the same conflict twice)?

e.g.,

```
$ git checkout feature-branch
$ git rebase master-branch
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in my-file
(manually resolve the conflict in my-file)
$ git add my-file
$ git rebase --continue
(get the exact same conflict in my-file again)
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in my-file
```

(I seem to recall I had a suspicion that the scenario I encountered had merge commits in feature-branch and/or master-branch and that was a precondition for the repeating conflict)

Comment: It's a bit tricky to create one of these. When you go to do it, remember that rebase is repeated cherry-picking: you want a setup in which resolving the conflict between cherry-picked commit P (parent) and current commit H (HEAD on the target branch) results in a new commit in which the same conflict will occur in parent C (child of P, to be cherry-picked next) when C goes atop P' (the copy you just built of P).

Comment: It's easy to elicit this in an interactive rebase where you edit an early commit. Happens to me all the time. No big deal, just keep resolving. I can't quite understand why you see this as problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if this is what you mean by "the same conflict":
(I'll try to give a full picture of the file's evolution at the bottom)

```
$ git checkout -b basebranch
$ echo test 123 > file.txt
$ git add file.txt
$ git commit -m '1'
$ cat file.txt
test 123

$ git checkout -b feature
$ echo test 456 >> file.txt
$ git commit -a -m 'a'
$ cat file.txt
test 123
test 456

$ # change the second line from 456 to ABC
$ echo test 123 > file.txt
$ echo test ABC >> file.txt
$ git commit -a -m 'b'
$ cat file.txt
test 123
test ABC

$ git checkout basebranch
$ echo ------ >> file.txt
$ git commit -a -m 'hyphens'
$ cat file.txt
test 123
------

$ git checkout feature
$ git rebase basebranch
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file.txt
$ cat file.txt
test 123
<<<<<<< HEAD
------
=======
test 456
>>>>>>> c150889 (a)

$ # resolve and put 456 after ----
$ echo test 123 > file.txt
$ echo ------ >> file.txt
$ echo test 456 >> file.txt
$ git add file.txt
$ cat file.txt
test 123
------
test 456

$ git rebase --continue
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file.txt
$ # Here is the 2nd conflict, which is similar to the 1st conflict (but not identical)
$ cat file.txt
test 123
<<<<<<< HEAD
------
test 456
=======
test ABC
>>>>>>> eb2fb01 (b)
```

If on the first conflict you resolve the conflict and put 456 after -----, when it applies your next commit it is still going to want to change 456 to ABC after a line that says 123 not after ---- so you will have to help git out again

Here is the first conflict:

[image: git gui with conflict; a text version follows this image]

```
$ git diff
diff --cc file.txt
index 2ee3b312b4,f28dd71184..0000000000
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@@ -1,2 -1,2 +1,6 @@@
  test 123
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +------
++=======
+ test 456
++>>>>>>> a
```

then if you resolve that

```
test 123
------
test 456
```

putting `test 456` after the line of hyphens... and continue

```
git add -A
git rebase --continue
```

[image: git gui showing conflict; text version of diff follows this image]

```
$ git diff
diff --cc file.txt
index 7329ce6fb4,acef073ce8..0000000000
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@@ -1,3 -1,2 +1,7 @@@
  test 123
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +------
 +test 456
++=======
+ test ABC
++>>>>>>> b
```

because it is expecting the `test 456` -> `test ABC` change to come after the line `test 123`, but it finds the line of hyphens and isn't sure that the change is still applicable.. or doesn't know how to make the change... or something.

so again you have to help it out.

```
test 123
------
test ABC
```

---

a couple comments about this:

- One "mistake" a lot of people make in a rebase like this is that.. if they know how the final code should look, they put the final answer in to an earlier commit... so for example... when you hit the final former conflict, you know that you have finally decided to put `ABC` not `456`, so you just put in the final answer.. instead of answering the question 'How can I apply this change in the new context?', people sometimes answer 'What should go here?' which can also lead to conflicts when applying later commits that are even harder to understand
- In some cases, if you don't care about the details in the feature branch, and would like to squash them all anyhow, it is helpful to squash the feature branch before rebasing against the basebranch.. then you only have to resolve the conflicts once:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase HEAD^^^ -i
# or
git rebase $(git merge-base HEAD basebranch)
```

- having to resolve two conflicts isn't necessarily a problem that needs to be avoided.  If each commit you are applying matters, taking a second to think how to apply that change in the new context is sometimes exactly what you want to do.  Solving the initial conflict (deciding how to apply commit 'a' given the changes to the base branch) does not tell you how to apply commit 'b'. that's a new question.  You are the only person who knows how the `456` -> `ABC` (`b`) change should be applied given the line of hyphens that you have added, and having told git how to apply the initial `456` change (`a`) doesn't change that.

Comment: I originally put `>` where I had meant to put `>>`.. so sorry if it didn't make much sense a few minutes ago. It's fixed now

Comment: Another issue is when you have squashed or modified commits in your base branch, and not your feature branch, so it tries to apply a bunch of commits in your feature branch that have already been applied in the base branch... when this happens, and you realise that the commit it is trying to apply is already in the base branch, just go `git rebase --skip` or when you rebase, use `-i` and review the commits that are going to be applied, and remove any that are already in the base branch but squashed or modified

Comment: Sorry if I'm rambling here.  I just think think rebasing is a really exciting topic.  I don't have much theoretical knowledge of it, but I have a lot of experience. So if my answer is missing some detail, and you think I might have the answer.. or if you think my answer is too long, but somewhere is the short answer you are looking for.. feel free to ask, and I will try to answer again if I still think I know the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Alex028502
I modified your commands a bit to make it clear what the file and conflict looks like inline with the commands.
I see what you've done here.  I don't think this is the scenario that I saw, as these conflicts are not identical.  My memory is about 90% sure, so not positive, and I wish I would have captured the exact scenario.  My memory is that I did not modify the lines that I added in the feature branch, but maybe I'm wrong there as well.

Answer (score -1):

`git-rebase` brings up merge conflicts per commit instead of per branch. So something like this should work:

```
git init
echo 'stuff' > file
git add file
git commit -m"Initial commit."
git checkout -b branch
echo 'different stuff' > file
git commit -m"First branch commit."
echo 'entirely different' > file
git add file
git commit -m"Second branch commit."
git rebase origin:master
```

Comment: This results in no conflicts because there are no changes made on the master branch to conflict with.